# Snap sees a more recent version of Firefox, but won't refresh to it?

Tags: firefox, snap

I'm trying to update Firefox on one of my computers to the latest version, and it won't seem to refresh even though it shows that a newer version is available. Has anyone seen this, or similar, behavior and/or have ideas on how to get the refresh/snap update to occur?

Terminal output below, system info below that:

```
$ killall firefox
firefox: no process found
$ sudo snap refresh
All snaps up to date.
$ snap info firefox
name:      firefox
summary:   Mozilla Firefox web browser
publisher: Mozilla✓
store-url: https://snapcraft.io/firefox
contact:   https://support.mozilla.org/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla
license:   unset
description: |
  Firefox is a powerful, extensible web browser with support for modern web application
  technologies.
commands:
  - firefox
  - firefox.geckodriver
snap-id:      3wdHCAVyZEmYsCMFDE9qt92UV8rC8Wdk
tracking:     latest/stable/ubuntu-23.04
refresh-date: 12 days ago, at 22:57 EDT
channels:
  latest/stable:    113.0-2       2023-05-09 (2645) 253MB -
  latest/candidate: 113.0-2       2023-05-05 (2645) 253MB -
  latest/beta:      114.0b2-1     2023-05-10 (2659) 255MB -
  latest/edge:      115.0a1       2023-05-10 (2660) 261MB -
  esr/stable:       102.11.0esr-2 2023-05-09 (2642) 186MB -
  esr/candidate:    102.11.0esr-2 2023-05-04 (2642) 186MB -
  esr/beta:         ↑
  esr/edge:         ↑
installed:          112.0.2-1                (2611) 255MB -


Operating System: Kubuntu 23.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.4
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.104.0
Qt Version: 5.15.8
Kernel Version: 6.2.0-20-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: Wayland
Processors: 6 × Intel® Core™ i5-9400F CPU @ 2.90GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you're using a "hidden" channel called `latest/stable/ubuntu-23.04` which hasn't had the latest release published to it (yet). Those channels are used by default on the release. You can switch to another channel using `snap refresh firefox --channel=latest/stable` for example.

Comment: `$ sudo snap refresh firefox --channel=latest/stable`
`firefox 113.0-2 from Mozilla✓ refreshed`

Thanks, I saw that in the `snap info` output but foolishly ignored it as I just assumed it was some sort of "distribution indicator" that wouldn't impact the channel. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The version you are considering may bot have been set for release as latest/stable.

Go to Ubuntu Software, select Firefox and use the drop down on the title bar and select a `latest/edge` version from there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but in this case I was looking to stick to the stable releases - and as popey pointed out I wasn't technically on the latest/stable channel, so switching to that solved it.